# How to set lightning tab label and maintain it for each call?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, workspaceapi

I have a LWC component on case page with button called `Search`, which does a callout and calls another LWC through Aura, that is opened as new tab in the same window, like this:

[image]

As you can see, within the main tab `00001713`, we can see 2 new tabs: `00001713` and `Edit Contact`.

The problems are:

1. The first time I click `Search` it changes the aura component's tab name to Edit Contact. But if click the LWC on case page again I see Loading....
2. The second time I click `Search` without refreshing, it changes the `00001713` tabs's name to Edit Contact. And because it the second time, problem 1 remains.

How can resolve these 2 problems?

LWC embedded on case page:

```
handleNavigate() {
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: "standard__component",
          attributes: {
              componentName: "c__PracticesResultsContainer"
          }
          ,
          state: {
              c__practices: JSON.stringify(this.practices),
              c__startPage: this.startPage,
              c__endPage: this.endPage,
              c__totalrecords: this.totalrecords,
              c__totalPages: this.totalPages,
              c__codeIndicated: this.practiceCodeIndicated,
              c__code: this.codeIndicated
          }
      });
  }
```

Aura:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="practices" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="codeIndicated" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="code" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="startPage" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="endPage" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalrecords" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalPages" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>

    <div class="slds-card">
        <c:practiceResult practicesString="{!v.practices}" practiceCodeIndicated="{!v.codeIndicated}" 
        startPage="{!v.startPage}" endPage="{!v.endPage}" totalrecords="{!v.totalrecords}" totalpages="{!v.totalPages}"
         code="{!v.code}"
        />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Aura component controller:

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = cmp.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            console.log('focusedTabId ' + focusedTabId);
            
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                label: "Edit Contact" //set label you want to set
            });
            
        });

        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        //var PaginationList = myPageRef.state.c__PaginationList;
        var practices = myPageRef.state.c__practices;
        var codeIndicated = myPageRef.state.c__codeIndicated;
        var startPage = myPageRef.state.c__startPage;
        var endPage = myPageRef.state.c__endPage;
        var totalrecords = myPageRef.state.c__totalrecords;
        var totalPages = myPageRef.state.c__totalPages;
        var code = myPageRef.state.c__code;

        
        cmp.set("v.practices", practices);
        cmp.set("v.codeIndicated", codeIndicated);
        cmp.set("v.startPage", startPage);
        cmp.set("v.endPage", endPage);
        cmp.set("v.totalrecords", totalrecords);
        cmp.set("v.totalPages", totalPages);
        cmp.set("v.code", code);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to set to subtab instead of tab

```
workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {}).then(function(subtabId) {
            // the subtab has been created, use the Id to set the label
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: subtabId,
                label: $A.get("$Label.c.SchoolConsultation_TitleShort")
            });

            workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : subtabId});                                
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error in container");
            console.log(error);
        });
```